# How to set google.maps.MapTypeId to earth view in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I configure Google Maps to show in Earth View? I am using Google Maps V3

Comment: Just to clarify what I think this is: there was a feature from 2010, which added an "Earth" button to Google Maps applets, see image [colosseum.PNG](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_7ZYqYi4xigk/TEid8dKoPJI/AAAAAAAAGgI/Sxn7bAuTwAc/s1600/colosseum.PNG) from [Google Lat Long: Earth view comes to Google Maps](http://google-latlong.blogspot.dk/2010/04/earth-view-comes-to-google-maps.html); also a video on [Earth View in Google Maps - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHe3ag3i8v8).

Answer (score 2):

Iff by "Earth View" you're referring to the Satellite view, you want to set your MapType as shown on [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#BasicMapTypes).

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use this,**

```
map.setMapTypeId('GoogleEarthAPI');
```

use this after setting up all things, like markers etc.

Good luck.